# Microblink: reading an image

Tags: ios, microblink

I'm asking the Microblink care reader to look at a photo of a card, rather than using the camera:

```
lazy var blinkCardRecognizer: MBCBlinkCardRecognizer = {
    return MBCBlinkCardRecognizer()
}()
lazy var recognizerCollection: MBCRecognizerCollection = {
    blinkCardRecognizer.extractCvv = false
    blinkCardRecognizer.extractIban = false
    blinkCardRecognizer.extractExpiryDate = false
    
    let recognizerList = [blinkCardRecognizer]
    return MBCRecognizerCollection(recognizers: recognizerList)
}()
```

My class has declared these two delegates:

```
MBCBlinkCardOverlayViewControllerDelegate, MBCScanningRecognizerRunnerDelegate
```

I'm sure that I'm passing this function a correct UIImage, and I do get to the `processImage` call:

```
func prepareToReadImage(_ theImage: UIImage?) {
    let recognizerRunner: MBCRecognizerRunner = MBCRecognizerRunner(recognizerCollection: recognizerCollection)
    recognizerRunner.scanningRecognizerRunnerDelegate = self
    
    var image: MBCImage? = nil
    if let anImage = theImage {
        image = MBCImage(uiImage: anImage)
    }
    image?.cameraFrame = true
    image?.orientation = MBCProcessingOrientation.left
    let _serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.microblink.DirectAPI-sample-swift")
    _serialQueue.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        recognizerRunner.processImage(image!)
    })
}
```

But this callback is not being hit:

```
func recognizerRunner(_ recognizerRunner: MBCRecognizerRunner, didFinishScanningWith state: MBCRecognizerResultState) {
    if state == .valid {
        print (state)
    }
}
```

Can you see why it isn't? Does it matter that I see the log warning `You are using time-limited license key!`?

Comment: Your `recognizerRunner` is a local variable and it will be released as soon as the function exits (which is before the recognition is complete). Make that a property instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

From the presented code, I can see that the `recognizerRunner` and the `prepareToReadImage` methods have been entered correctly.
However, in the first block of code, where you're defining the recognizer and the `recognizerCollection`, I can see that the issue could be with the `MBCRecognizerCollection` since its parameter, `recognizers`, is of type `[MBCRecognizer]`, and you're placing there `[MBCBlinkCardRecognizer]`. I can suggest this solution to see if it works:

```
    blinkCardRecognizer = MBCBlinkCardRecognizer()
    var recognizerList = [MBCRecognizer]()
    
    let recognizerCollection: MBCRecognizerCollection = {
        blinkCardRecognizer.extractCvv = false
        blinkCardRecognizer.extractIban = false
        blinkCardRecognizer.extractExpiryDate = false
        
        recognizerList.append(blinkCardRecognizer!)
        return MBCRecognizerCollection(recognizers: recognizerList)
    }()

    recognizerRunner = MBCRecognizerRunner(recognizerCollection: recognizerCollection)
```

The only difference is that I've previously defined the BlinkCardRecognizer and the RecognizerRunner, so that should not make any difference:

```
private var recognizerRunner: MBCRecognizerRunner?
private var blinkCardRecognizer: MBCBlinkCardRecognizer?
```

Just to add here, it does not matter if you see the `You are using time-limited license key!`, it is simply an indicator that you using a time-limited key and it should not affect the scanning process.

Comment: Thank you, Milan, `didFinishScanning` now gets called. The state, however, is always `empty`. Any idea why that might be? (I am using what appears to be a good quality jpeg of the credit card)

Comment: Does the issue only happen with one card, or on multiple ones? Also is the card real, or is it a sample, for instance, found on the internet?

Comment: I have tried with two different credit cards (visa and MC), both my personal, both valid. I took the pictures of both with the phone camera. I could show you one of them (redacted of course! lol) if you would like.

Comment: Hi coco, I've also given you an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66656255/microblink-successfully-reading-an-image/66690878#66690878

Let me know if it helped. :)